# Postgres missing pgcrypt ability?

Tags: postgresql, jetty, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to run a Java Jetty application and I keep seeing this error:

```
Caused by: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function crypt(character varying, character) does not exist|  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.|  Where: PL/pgSQL function
```

Does anyone recognize this or how to solve the issue? I thought pgcrypt was prebundled in Postgres 9.1.x?

I currently run Mac OSX Lion 10.7 and installed Postgres using brew "brew install postgres".

Comment: Even if `pgcrypto` is prebundled, the `crypt()` signature is `crypt(text, text)` and not `crypt(character varying, character)` as seen from your error message (bear in mind `text` is equivalent to `character varying`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just had to enable pgcrypto;
Just ran from the CLI:

> CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

For mac users I recommend reading more about it on brew:

> brew info postgres

Comment: Thank you for suggesting enabling this extension. I was checking in postgres 9.5.3, how to create uuid, automatically. I found https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/uuid-ossp.html and it suggesting to use 'gen_random_uuid();' function. I Enabled this extension and it works!
`development-db# SELECT gen_random_uuid();
           gen_random_uuid
--------------------------------------
 40a3e789-a685-4585-abbc-a0a4829402b7
(1 row)`